# Java incompatible type boolean and char

Tags: java

Im programming a text adventure, and i am getting these errors:

```
Error:(59, 45) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to boolean
Error:(60, 29) java: incomparable types: boolean and char
Error:(60, 36) java: bad operand types for binary operator '&&'
  first type:  boolean
  second type: char
Error:(64, 26) java: incomparable types: java.lang.Boolean and char
Error:(64, 33) java: bad operand types for binary operator '&&'
  first type:  boolean
  second type: char
```

i am new to java, (about a week of experience) and have tried altering && to ||, changing to boolean and back to string.

```
switch (firstChoice){
            case "go to mailbox":
                System.out.println("The mailbox is closed. Open it?(y/n");
                userInput.nextLine();
                String mailbox;
                mailbox = userInput.nextLine();
                if (mailbox == 'Y' && 'y')
                System.out.println("The mailbox is rusted shut. Pull harder?");
```

The output should be The mailbox is rusted shut. Pull harder?

Comment: `firstChoice` seems to bee a `boolean` and thus can have only values `true` or `false`. You try to compare it with the `String "go to mailbox"`.

Comment: In your own words, in plain English, what do you expect `mailbox == 'Y' && 'y'` to mean?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel if the user input is Y or y, say that The mailbox is rusted shut.

Comment: @TheRedRipper If you have any compilation error, please add your complete code(class). It will help debug the problem.

Comment: Maybe change the ' ' single quotations to double " ", since it's a string you're getting it out of, not a char. However you would need to do a .equals() in that case.

Answer (score 6):

First, you are comparing a `String` with `==` ([don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/2970947)) to a character . Second, you want an or (not an and) and finally, it would be cleaner with `equalsIgnoreCase`. Like,

```
if (mailbox.equals("Y") || mailbox.equals("y"))
```

or using [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) and [`String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) like

```
if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(mailbox))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out `if("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(mailbox))` instead of `if (mailbox == 'Y' && 'y')`, this should work.